# QoQ changes by Customer in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to create a DAX formula to calculate the increases and decreases of customers across periods. Following is a sample of the data that I have

```
Year-Quarter|Customer|Credit-Limit
2019Q2|A|50
2019Q2|B|100
2019Q2|C|100
2019Q2|D|200
2019Q2|E|1000
2019Q2|F|200
2019Q3|A|50
2019Q3|B|200
2019Q3|C|100
2019Q3|D|50
2019Q3|E|500
2019Q3|F|300
```

I am looking to create a summary by Year-Quarter showing the number of customers that had an increase/decrease/none of their Credit-Limit.
Note that this is just a sample and the actual data is >10M rows. So even though I can create another table, I think from a computation standpoint, a measure would be more useful

Desired Output:

A commentary like the following: "There are 2 customers that have increased credit limit in 2019Q3"

Done so far:

```
Prev Quarter Credit Limit = 
VAR CurrentYearQuarter = MAX(Sheet1[Year-Quarter])
VAR Quarter_Year =
    LEFT (CurrentYearQuarter, 4)
VAR Quarter_period =
    RIGHT (CurrentYearQuarter, 1 )
RETURN
    IF (
            Quarter_period = "1",
            CALCULATE (
                SUM ( Sheet1[Credit Limit] ),
               Sheet1[Year-Quarter]
                    = ( Quarter_Year - 1 )

                    & "Q"
                    & ( Quarter_period + 3 )
            ),
            CALCULATE (
                SUM ( Sheet1[Credit Limit] ),
                Sheet1[Year-Quarter]
                    = Quarter_Year 
                    & "Q"
                    & Quarter_period - 1
            )
        ) 

Inc/Dec = IF(SUM(Sheet1[Credit Limit]) - [Prev Quarter Credit Limit] > 0,"Inc",
 IF(SUM(Sheet1[Credit Limit]) - [Prev Quarter Credit Limit] < 0,"Dec","None"))

Commentary = "There are " &
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[Customer]), 
FILTER(Sheet1, [Inc/Dec] = "Inc" && Sheet1[Year-Quarter] = "2019Q3"))
```

Current output:

Commentary: "There are 4"

I am not sure why I am getting 4 as compared to 2 as the number here. Help or guidance would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've slightly altered the input data for experimental purpose, I've added

```
2018Q3 | A | 200
2018Q4 | A | 50
2019Q1 | A | 50
```

I've added a Quarter-Calendar (which is a calculated table using `VALUES(Sheet1[Year-Quarter])`

Then by adding more columns to this new table, extracting the current year and quarter using `LEFT` and `RIGHT`, then calculating the previous quarter, previous year and combining to a Prevoius-Year-Quarter column:

[image]]

Using this Q-Calendar I create a 1:* relationship to the Sheet1 table between [Year-Quarter] and [Year-Quarter], then I create a second inactive 1:* relationship between [Previous-Year-Quarter] and [Year-Quarter] like this:

[image]

I then create two measures, one for sum of previous quarter credit an one for current quarter credit:

```
Current-Quater CL = 
var currentQ = MAX('Q-Calendar'[Year-Quarter])
var tempTable = 
FILTER(
    ALL('Q-Calendar');
    'Q-Calendar'[Year-Quarter] = currentQ
)

return
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Sheet1'[Credit-Limit ]);
    tempTable
)
```

In the [Previous-Quarter CL] measure I use `USERELATIONSHIP` to activate the passive relationship I added from the Q-Calendar.

```
Prev-Quater CL = 
var currentQ = MAX('Q-Calendar'[Year-Quarter])
var tempTable = 
FILTER(
    ALL('Q-Calendar');
    'Q-Calendar'[Year-Quarter] = currentQ
)

return
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Sheet1'[Credit-Limit ]);
    tempTable;
    USERELATIONSHIP('Sheet1'[Year-Quarter]; 'Q-Calendar'[Previous-Year-Quarter])
)
```

Then create the Inc/Dec measure like this:

```
Increase/Decrease = 
var temp = [Current-Quater CL]-[Prev-Quater CL]

return
SWITCH(
    TRUE();
    temp > 0; "Increase";
    temp < 0; "Decrease";
    "No change"
)
```

And finally created a new (actually 3 new) Commentary measures like this:

```
Commentary_2 = "There are " &
var customers = VALUES(Sheet1[Customer])

return
SUMX(
    customers;
    CALCULATE(
        IF(
            [Current-Quater CL]-[Prev-Quater CL] > 0;
            1;
            0
        )
    )
)&" customers how have increased their credit"
```

Using the Year-Quarter column from the Q-calendar as a slicer I get the current status and I can select a previous quarter to see the status at that time:

[image]

[image]

N.B: The code in my measures can be optimised, I just kept them as detailed as this to make it more understandable.